# HTML5: Voice input issues

Tags: html, google-chrome, web, voice-recognition

Please have a look at the following code.

```
<html>
<form method="get" action="http://www.google.com/search">
      <input type="text" name="q" size="30" x-webkit-speech/>
      <input type="submit" value="Google Search" />
    </form>
</html>
```

This suppose to display a mic icon and take the voice input in Google Chrome right? But that is not happening. I don't see any mic icon and this do not take any voice input too.

I checked with www.google.com to see whether the mic icon appear and voice recognition works. Yes it does, something is wrong with my code for sure. what have I done wrong? I am having the latest Google Chrome too.

Comment: Yes it does. It won't find a server to process though. [(See this)](http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/E28RT/) Shows the mic and accepts the voice just fine.

Comment: @abhitalks: You mean the code works? Then why it do not work in mine?

Comment: and also see this: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/A2Q6pQI4xmQ

Comment: @abhitalks: ahh, you mean it no longer work due to some reason right? That what the posts in the links says.

Comment: Ya, it seems so. As per that, `x-webkit-speech` is getting deprecated. Perhaps was just an experimental thing. Go with Javascript API.

Comment: @abhitalks: what is the JavaScript API?

Comment: This: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html

Comment: @abhitalks: One more question. I not a web developer and has never worked with JavaScript APIs. Do I have to install something?

Comment: Not really. Just go thru a few tutorials and you will get the idea. [Googling HTML5 Javascript Voice API](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=HTML5+Javascript+Voice+API&oq=HTML5+Javascript+Voice+API) will yield many.

Comment: @abhitalks: Thanks. Please provide your comments as an answer.

Comment: even though it doesn't look like an answer, i have added it. :) thanks.

Comment: To be clear, on linux the mic icon does not show up in the input,textarea or address bar using the x-webkit-speech. The jsfiddle mentioned and suggested in comments and as accepted answer fail. And the suggestions to google HTML5 voice api assume most haven't. Hence, still an open question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. It won't find a server to process though.

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/E28RT/

Its Shows the mic and accepts the voice just fine.

However, as mentioned [in this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/A2Q6pQI4xmQ) `x-webkit-speech` is getting deprecated. It perhaps was just an experimental thing. It is advised to go with the HTML5 Javascript Voice/Speech API. Ref here: https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/speechapi.html . Even that is going to be heavily browser dependent as of this writing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Depending on which browser?

Comment: @HashMap: As you know HTML5 is evolving and every browser has its own implementation. Although many HTML5/CSS3 specific implementations have now been more or less standardized across browsers using vendor specific prefixes, there are still some implementations which just don't work across browsers. e.g. this `x-webkit-speech` which you encountered is specific to webkit browsers and that too Chrome typically. Similarly, Speech API is still not mature and hence you will run into browser specific issues. You may refer [http://caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=speech) for compatibilities.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/E28RT/ - this do not show the mic or accept the voice..

Comment: which browser? its working just fine on my "chrome v34.0.1847.137 m"

Comment: mine is - Version 35.0.1916.114 m

Comment: hmmm.. it means google has already dropped support of `x-webkit-speech` from v35 onwards!

Answer (score 2):

please checkout this site:
[HTML5-Speech-Recognition-API](http://shapeshed.com/html5-speech-recognition-api/)

This should be what you're looking for.

Greetz

Comment: this perhaps the best current reference and answer